# running wf workflow from mvc controller

Tags: model-view-controller, workflow-foundation

enter code hereI intend to use WF4.5 in a web application which is written by MVC Framework. I have used WorkflowApplication class instance to run my WorkFlow with. but whenever i call the method in controller that run the instance I get this error:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous  operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it

I have written this class which is resposnsible to execute workflow:

```
 public class WorkFlowsPipeline : IWorkFlowsPipeline
    {
        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private SqlWorkflowInstanceStore _instanceStore;

        public WorkFlowsPipeline(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            //workflowInstanceStore
            _instanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore();
            _instanceStore.ConnectionString ="data source=.;initial catalog=WFPersist;user id=sa;password=1;";
        }

        public void RecordPersistedInstanceForTheUser(int userId,Guid instanceId, Models.Enums.WorkFlowTypeEnum workFlowType)
        {
            _unitOfWork.UsersWorkFlows.Add(new UsersWorkFlowsInstance
            {
                UserId = userId,
                WorkFlowId=instanceId,
                WorkFlowType = workFlowType
            });
        }


        public void RunCompleteProfileForUser(int userId)
        {
            var usersWorkFlow = _unitOfWork.UsersWorkFlows.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);
            if (usersWorkFlow == null)
            {
                Activity rentalWorkflow = new Activity1();

                Dictionary<string, object> wfArg = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {
                        "UOW", _unitOfWork
                    },
                    {
                        "UserId",userId
                    }
                };

                var _wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(rentalWorkflow, wfArg);


                _wfApp.SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
                _wfApp.InstanceStore = _instanceStore;
                //_wfApp.Extensions.Add(this);

                var instanceId=_wfApp.Id;
                _wfApp.Run();

                RecordPersistedInstanceForTheUser(userId, instanceId,WorkFlowTypeEnum.CompleteProfile);


            }
            else
            {
                //get id of instance load it from database and run it
            }
        }


    }
```

and I called the method in my controller action in this way:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {

            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();

            _workFlowsPipeline.RunCompleteProfileForUser(userId);

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: I have posted my code. It is so simple i do not see anything special in it . I am really in doubt in ASP.net MVC treads ability to execute WF. I saw an example of using MVC with WF but using AsyncControllers. I wondered if it is needed doing that? I used the popular Async Await keywords in my action but it did not work. may be i should use WCF services in order to have WF into my MVC project Although my project architecture is not SOA. please help me find my way.

Comment: Actually i expected more documents and examples of using WF in MVC framework. Sometimes i think WF is a dead technology that is no longer used in real world.

Comment: WF isnt dead according to Microsoft, although not much has been done on it lately it is still part of .NET 4.6. Which line of code is throwing this error? There is no reason that you should not be able to run WF from your controller actions. On a side note, looking at your code, you use Dependency Injection to inject the IUnitOfWork, consider using it to inject SqlWorkflowInstanceStore as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use WorkflowInvoker instead of WorkflowApplication.

Comment: thanks. but as i know WorkflowInvoker is so limited that we can not even persist workflows with it.

Comment: That is correct. But if you need to use WorkflowApplication than you will have to re-architect your solution. I guess the simplest way to go would be WorklfowServices.